# How to view joint words of devnagari fonts?

Tags: fonts

What I am seeing is

[image: What I am seeing]

What I want to see is

[image: I want to see]

I am using Google input tools plugin in Chromium.

Edits: 
 1. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
 2. This problems persist on whole system. Not only in Chromium

Comment: Ubuntu version? On other programs does it work correctly and the problem is just there, does it work with another user, or is it a system-wide problem?

Comment: Is the `fonts-deva` package installed? Have you tried to change the fonts setting in Chromium?

Comment: @dadexix86 I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am seeing this problem everywhere on system

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes I'd fonts-deva installed and also tried changing fonts in chromium. Nothing Worked! :(

Comment: You may want to try some of the input sources for Hindi etc. which are shipped with Ubuntu. By installing the `ibus-m17n` package quite a few such input source options are added. (Attempt at a workaround rather than solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after setting up  **Noto Sans Devnagri** font on a whole system including Chromium.

**For system:** Install Unity Tweak Tools and setup 'Noto Sans Devnagri' font there.

For **Chrome/Chromium:** Go to settings, select fonts and choose 'Noto Sans Devnagri' there.

You can download the font for free from here: https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: Please add a few more details here about how to set up that font.

Comment: Answer Updated.